# Programatically get the class of the belongs_to association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reflection, ruby-on-rails-4, classname

Let's say I have some classes linked by a one-to-many relationship:

```
class A
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :b

class B
  field :title, type: String 
  belongs_to :a
```

Let's also say I have an instance of B and I want to retrieve the class name(s) of his belongs_to relationship (in my example 'A', not the instance of type A linked to my B object).

```
a = A.new name: 'my A object'
b = B.new title: 'my B object', a: a

assert_equal b.get_relationships(:belongs_to), ['A'] #substitute "get_relationships" with something that actually exists :)
```

What should I do?

I had a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371574/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-belongs-to-associations) on a similar topic (using reflection) but I couldn't manage to make it work. Maybe something has changed in Rails 4?

Comment: `B.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
B.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name)
```

or

```
b.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name)
```

Comment: You should use `:class_name` instead to account for the `class_name` option, like `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`.

Comment: What if there are multiple classes that have a has_many associations to your b object?