# Get list of all belongs_to models in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have these two models:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :review, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Review model holds one key which helps me to get all the Reviews which belong to some user.

I can get all those Reviews like this:

```
@reviews = Review.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
```

For one review I would just do this:

```
@review = Review.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).first
@article = @review.article
```

But how can I now from a list of @reviews get a list of all articles which are connected to those reviews?

Answer (score 0):

If the `@article = @review.article` code works then your just asking how to iterate over a collection of reviews? In that case

```
@reviews = Review.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)

# in your view
@reviews.each do |review|
  review.article
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [collect](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
articles = @reviews.collect {|review| review.article}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean list all of related models with your any model. Your answer is here clearly;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784574/3425913

```
Thing.reflections.collect{|a, b| b.class_name if b.macro==:belongs_to}.compact
```

You can call :has_many or :has_one associations too

Answer (score 0):

You could eager load the associations

```
@reviews = Review.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:reviewable)
```

and if you really need all of the the reviewables, you can:-

```
@reviewables = @reviews.map(&:reviewable).uniq
```