# Rename foreign keys automatically in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm doing a rails migration to rename a table and I'd like to rename its foreign keys automatically. E.g. a `User` has many `posts`, and I'm renaming `User` to `Person`

```
def change
  rename_table :users, :people
end
```

I'd like to create automatically migrations like

```
def change
  rename_column :posts, :user_id, :person_id
end
```

I've thought to get the model form the migration and look at its `has_many` models, e.g. as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136941/165753). Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I think it's not possible. It would be too error prone.

Comment: I like this change. I never understood why software developers (like drug dealers) use to call their customers *users*.

Answer (score 5):

It would be great if Rails offered to rename foreign keys but I didn't find how to tell it to do that.
You can however do the following for each table referencing `users`:

```
remove_foreign_key :posts, :users
rename_column      :posts, :user_id, :person_id
add_foreign_key    :posts, :people
```

This preserves the references you already have.

Be careful with table names as `remove_foreign_key` does not pluralize the names for you if you forget to do it (some generators do, or warn you in case you use the singular instead of the plural).

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 6 you can just do `rename_table` and `rename_column` and Rails takes care of the foreign_keys for you.